# Create count for series of values grouped by specific column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to create a count for a series of values grouped by specific column in Python

**Data**

```
id  date    type    
aa  q1 23   hi  
aa  q1 23   hi  
aa  q1 23   bye 
aa  q1 23   bye 
aa  q2 23   hi  
aa  q2 23   bye 
bb  q1 23   hi
```

resets for every unique date and id

**Desired**

```
 id date    type     count
aa  q1 23   hi       hi01
aa  q1 23   hi       hi02
aa  q1 23   bye      bye01
aa  q1 23   bye      bye02
aa  q2 23   hi       hi01
aa  q2 23   bye      bye02
bb  q1 23   hi       hi01
```

**Doing**

I am adding leading zeros - keep getting type error

```
df['count'] = df[0].str.upper() + df[1].str.zfill(2)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['count'] = df['type'] + df.groupby([*df]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```

Output:

```
   id   date type  count
0  aa  q1 23   hi   hi01
1  aa  q1 23   hi   hi02
2  aa  q1 23  bye  bye01
3  aa  q1 23  bye  bye02
4  aa  q2 23   hi   hi01
5  aa  q2 23  bye  bye01
6  bb  q1 23   hi   hi01
```